# Grouping or Sorting Data in EPPlus without displaying all cells in a column

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

**NOTE:** I just realized Excel incremented the report numbers, ignore that they will be the same for each row per group.

I have a data table coming back from the database that looks something like this

[Original Table Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilgey.png)

I am trying to get it to look like this in the Excel output. I have read articles on Outlining, but I am not sure that is what I am really after. I am trying to "group" the data by that case number field, but not repeat the data for each row, since it will be the same. The data that is different for each grouping is the payees and their amounts.

[Formatted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p5OK.png)

Just looking for insight on using EPPlus for this or any advice from others who have come across something similar.

Comment: I hope you find a better answer, but I think you will have to do the grouping manually. I find this is all too common with EPPlus. You will have to group your data (maybe using linq's `GroupBy()`), and then only print the first 4 column values for the first row in each group.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be achieved with Linq. Not seeing any code it's a bit hard to produce a good example but the results should be achievable with the following idea:

First do a foreach where you fill in the excel cells with Case_Number, Docket, Agency_Name and Report_Number and then do a second foreach to go through the payments

```
var results = GetResults(); //However you retrieve your collection from DB

var groupedResults = results.GroupBy(a => new { 
    a.Case_Number, 
    a.Docket, 
    a.Agency_Name, 
    a.Report_Number}).Select(b => b.FirstOrDefault());

foreach(var group in groupedResults)      
{
    // Fill the cells
    foreach(var payment in results.Where(a => 
 a.Case_Number == group.Case_Number
 && a.Docket == group.Docket
 && a.Agency_Name == group.Agency_Name 
 && a.Report_Number == group.Report_Number)
    {
        // Fill the payment detail cells and increment the row counter
    }
}
```

Admittedly the second foreach is pretty rough, but I haven't found a better way. Hopefully someone is able to provide more elegant solution

Comment: Sorry for not including any code, currently I get this data back in the form of a DataTable through an SQL SP call.